# Simplifying $\frac{^n\mathrm{C}_k}{^n\mathrm{C}_{k-1}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial

Question asks to simplify:

$$\frac{^n\mathrm{C}_k}{^n\mathrm{C}_{k-1}}$$

I have a few steps but not sure if its correct.

$$\begin{align*}\frac{(n)!}{(n-k)!(k)!} \bigg/ \frac{(n)!}{(n-k-1)!(k-1)!} & = \frac{(n-k+1)!(k-1)!}{(n-k)!k!} \\ & = \frac{(n-k+1)!(k-1)k!}{(n-k)!k!}\end{align*}$$

Do the $k!$'s cancel out? Because I cancelled them

then I finally get $\dfrac{(n-k+1)!(k-1)}{(n-k)!}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{^n\mathrm{C}_k}{^n\mathrm{C}_{k-1}} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!} \cdot \frac{(n-(k-1))!(k-1)!}{n!} = \frac{(n-k+1)\color{blue}{(n-k)!}\color{red}{(k-1)!}}{\color{blue}{(n-k)!} k\color{red}{(k-1)!}} = \frac{n-k+1}{k}$$

Comment: I get everything except the last part where you have (n - k)! on the numerator. How?

Comment: Call $n-k = z$ then you have $(n- (k-1)) = (n-k +1) = (z+1)$ so $$\frac{(n-k+1)!}{(n-k)!} = \frac{(z+1)!}{z!} = \frac{(z+1)z!}{z!} = z+1 = n-k+1$$

Comment: oh I finally get it, thanks people! @ZainPatel

Comment: thanks for the edit man appreciate it! @ZainPatel

Comment: No worries. :-)

Comment: Hey @ZainPatel bro, if you dont mind me asking man doesnt K! = (k - 1)k! cause in your answer its saying k(k-1)! or is that the same thing. Sorry man im just dumb

Comment: Nope! $k! = k(k-1)!$ not the other way around. Look at it like this: $$k! = k \, \, \, \underbrace{(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)\cdots (2)(1)}_{(k-1)!} = k(k-1)!$$

Comment: Oh i see the trick, cheers brother you've just helped me with the only question I was stuck with.

Comment: Glad I helped, thanks for your kind words. :-)